# PyQGIS export to JSON: writeAsVectorFormat and precision

Tags: qgis, python, vector, pyqgis, precision

In my QGIS plugin qgis2leaf I am exporting all layers as JSON into a JSON directory. Therefore I would like to enable the user to define the precision in the GUI. The normal "save as" dialogue in QGIS has the possibility to define the precision:

[image: GEOJSON export with the save as dialogue]

Is there any possibility to use a precision in the writeAsVectorFormat?
The found documentation gives me no clue:

```
QgsVectorFileWriter::WriterError QgsVectorFileWriter::writeAsVectorFormat   (   QgsVectorLayer *    layer,
        const QString &     fileName,
        const QString &     fileEncoding,
        const QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem *    destCRS,
        const QString &     driverName = "ESRI Shapefile",
        bool    onlySelected = false,
        QString *   errorMessage = 0,
        const QStringList &     datasourceOptions = QStringList(),
        const QStringList &     layerOptions = QStringList(),
        bool    skipAttributeCreation = false,
        QString *   newFilename = 0 
    )       [static]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be set in the "layerOptions" parameter. This parameter takes a list of strings of the format "OPTION=VALUE", corresponding to OGR layer options for the vector format. So, for coordinate precision, try setting this parameter to:

```
['COORDINATE_PRECISION=3']
```

(or whatever your desired precision is). Additional valid parameters are listed on the OGR website: http://www.gdal.org/drv_geojson.html

edit:

So your code would be:

```
qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i,dataStore + os.sep + 'exp_' + safeLayerName + '.js', 'utf-8', exp_crs, 'GeoJSON', layerOptions=['COORDINATE_PRECISION=3'])
```

Comment: given this syntax:
qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i,dataStore + os.sep + 'exp_' + safeLayerName + '.js', 'utf-8', exp_crs, 'GeoJson') ||
How would this look like? I am a newbie,... sorry!
Would this be right: qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(i,dataStore + os.sep + 'exp_' + safeLayerName + '.js', 'utf-8', exp_crs, 'GeoJson', false, 0,  ['COORDINATE_PRECISION=3'])